# log vaule in excel cell

Tags: excel, logging, vba

I have a large excel file with scripts running to collect data from various locations. One of the cells in the sheet generates a two digit number every 10th minute. I would like to collect this number in this specific cell every 10th minute and log the value in a different sheet or a log (doesn't matter which format) Right now we can just read the value as it is displayed, but we keep a log to trace the ups and downs.

Comment: don't see the real question here - if you run the script what is keeping you from writing the cell value to another sheet after everything is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see **edited answer**

When you open the sheet you hit the start timer button, then when you want it to stop press the stop timer.. this will copy the value from E15 to Sheet 2 A1 and below every 1 hour 1 second.

Taken and edited from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/379070-simple-copy-update-cell-value-every-minute.html)

Please make sure you make a copy and try it on that first.

1. Open up your workbook
2. Get into VB Editor (Press Alt+F11)
3. Insert a new module (Insert > Module)
4. Copy and Paste in your code

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Public dTime As Date

   Sub ValueStore()
   Dim dTime As Date
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("E15").Value
   Call StartTimer
   End Sub


   Sub StartTimer()
   dTime = Now + TimeValue("01:00:01")
   Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True
   End Sub

   Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=False
   End Sub
   ```
5. Get out of VBA (Press Alt+Q)
6. Save your sheet
7. Click on the Control Toolbox Command Button icon
8. Draw a button on your worksheet
9. Right-click the button and select Properties
10. Change the Caption to Start Timer
11. Right-click the button and select View Code
12. Paste in this code for the command button:

    ```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call StartTimer
    End Sub
    ```
13. Switch back to your spreadsheet
14. Repeat steps 7-12 to create a Stop Timer button

    ```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Call StopTimer
    End Sub
    ```
15. Press Alt-Q to close the VBEditor and save your sheet

Try the buttons :)

Comment: Doesn't really work for me. To give more exact information maybe you can modify it? Sheet 1 has a value in cell E15 which updates every hour. This is the production volume / hour at our customer. This needs to be logged since we want to track the ups and downs in the pace. The value needs to be copied once a hour to Sheet 2 A1 and descending. Im not used to vbs scripts and are just trying to modify and add things on demand since I was not the original developer for this workbook.

Comment: Great! Since it didn't work in the actual sheet Im using I will have to do some digging. Since we have gpo's restricting use of unsigned macros I have to open Excel with my admin account in order to run. Nevertheless, I created a new Excel file with only values in the cell and then it works. Thank you very much.