# Automatic timestamp

Tags: excel, logging, timestamp, vba

The following is running.
If I would like a time and date stamp created in column B when a value is insterted into column A, how can I modify the existing module? 
(I couldn't paste the code, that's why there is a link)

[Log Value in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118467/log-vaule-in-excel-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a small change to that line:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 2).Value = Array(Range("E15").Value, Now())
```

Edit: I'm not sure why you have changed your question to remove the code you posted originally!?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will check if there any changes in the last line sheet2,
the time stamp will be printed in the Column B

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp)) Is Nothing Then

   lastrow = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = Now()
End If
```

End Sub